# Output of a table which is based on XML Schema

Tags: xml, oracle, select, schema

I'm having a problem with data output using SQLDeveloper. This is my first time using xml and creating xml schemas, so i'm sure someone can help me with what i'm doing wrong. So I created this xml schema file which basically stores info about artists and their corresponding albums. I'll upload the full code to google drive because it's quite long.

albumrecordsshema.xsd :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1wJgekHHK81SW1nZ3JWZHpQVk0/view

After i created that, i registered it in database using this code:

```
BEGIN
    DBMS_XMLSCHEMA.REGISTERSCHEMA(
    SCHEMAURL => 'http://localhost:8080/public/albumrecordsshema.xsd',
    SCHEMADOC => bfilename ('XMLDIR', 'albumrecordsshema.xsd'),
    CSID => nls_charset_id ('AL32UTF8')
    );
END;
```

Then i made a table from that schema

```
CREATE TABLE albumrecords OF XMLTYPE
XMLSCHEMA "http://localhost:8080/public/albumrecordsshema.xsd"
ELEMENT "albumrecords";
```

Everything worked, table was created and so was the schema. Then i inserted some values from xml file. And again, xml file is too long, so here's the link to it:

albumrecords.xml
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1wJgekHHK81dVNteGhOTF9xX3c/view

But now when i try to see the data, it doesn't go further than few lines.
Here's the select statement i'm using:

```
select a.getclobval() from albumrecords a;
```

Output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="WINDOWS-1257"?>                                    
<albumrecords>                                                                   
  <album_artist art
```

Am i doing something wrong? Any help with my problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875997/oracle-extract-from-xml-truncating-value). Some info [here](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Database/Oracle/Q_28455451.html).

Comment: yes, that was it. i had to use setlong in order to output the data correctly. thank you.