# oracle SQL select query is returing only first condition

Tags: sql, oracle, select

Sql select is returning only first condition when I run through SQL plus

SQL:

```
Select '<Item UID="' || ItemUri || '" ItemNum="' || ItemNum ||'" LogRequestID="' || REPLACE (LogRequestID,'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>') ||'">' || substr(ITEMRESULTS,39) || '</Item>'
from DATATABLE_01
where ITEMSTATUS=2
AND SUBSTR(ITEMURI,60,10) IN ('202001396','A02004930','A02005236','A02006444','A02006746','A02007228','A02007599','A02007948')
order by ITEMNUM;
```

Output is returning like below

```
<ITEMUID="'||ITEMURI||'"ITEMNUM="'||ITEMNUM||'"LOGREQUESTID="'||REPLACE(LOGREQU
<Item UID="BaseOverallFulfillmentAccount/overallFulfillmentAccountKey=202001396"
```

Need entire output please anybody help on this

Comment: possible duplicate of [Oracle extract from xml truncating value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20875997/oracle-extract-from-xml-truncating-value)

Answer (score 0):

This isn't an issue with Oracle, it's an issue with whatever tool you're using to display the results.  Consider increasing the displayed data length limit in your tool.

Answer (score 0):

In sqlplus, you can set the linesize parameter to be able to display more information on a line.

```
SET LINESIZE 1000
```